# WooCommerce and SimpleModal - How to list products from a category

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, simplemodal

I am trying to create an option within WordPress / WooCommerce that will utilize jQuery to launch a modal window using the Simple Modal Window Plugin by Eric Martin:  http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I'm able to implement the modal window and pull via ajax a page into the modal window using:

```
        jQuery('#battery-selector').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('<div ></div>').load('http://vapelife.creativesparkdev.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-vapelife/templates/product-select.php').modal(); // AJAXL
    return false;
});
```

Now, because I am loading a page outside of the WordPress framework, I'm not able to load a category of products with the a loop.  Any ideas how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of call, `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins-themes/whatever/file.php`, is not correct. No plugin or theme file is made to work like this (it can be, but on rare and specially coded occasions).

This way works:

```
jQuery('<div ></div>').load('http://example.com/some-real-page-url/').modal();
```

Create a page with the desired template (`some-real-page-url`) and load it in your AJAX call.

But I tested the simple modal with TwentyEleven/Twelve/Thirteen and it did not behave well. Maybe the [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) will have to be heavily customized, i.e., your own header instead of `get_header()`.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo for the response, I'll give this a shot tomorrow.  I'm assuming if I load the page from a template it will be within the framework... this might be a great starting point.  I'll let you know how I make out.

Comment: Brasofilo - thank you for the help - you've put me on the right path.  I marked your answer.